# How to implement logout functionality in Vue app having laravel passport as api auth with httponly cookie authorization?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I m trying to implement api authentication in my vue app , api made with laravel and laravel passport.Since LocalStorage is not safe for storing token so i tried to saved in httponly cookie which is safer than local storage. i able to implement login function and cookie sucessfully get stored in browser with httponly flag.

**Here is the code of api routes:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
Route::get('/testapi',function(){
    return array("message"=>"Api fetched sucesfully");
});

Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
  
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth.api'], function() {
    Route::get('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
});
```

**AuthController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use Cookie;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
   /* public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }*/
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $token =  $user->createToken('Personal Access Token')->accessToken;
            $cookie = $this->getCookieDetails($token);
            return response()
                ->json([
                    'logged_in_user' => $user,
                    'token' => $token,
                ], 200)
                ->withCookie($cookie['name'], $cookie['value'], $cookie['minutes'], $cookie['path'], $cookie['domain'], $cookie['secure'], $cookie['httponly'], $cookie['samesite']);
        } else {
            return response()->json(
                ['error' => 'invalid-credentials'], 422);
        }
    }
    private function getCookieDetails($token)
    {
        return [
            'name' => '_token',
            'value' => $token,
            'minutes' => 1440,
            'path' => null,
            'domain' => null,
            // 'secure' => true, // for production
            'secure' => null, // for localhost
            'httponly' => true,
            'samesite' => true,
        ];
    }
    public function logout(Request $request  )
    {   
        $request->user()->token()->revoke();
        /*Auth::user()->tokens->each(function($token,$key){
            $token->delete();
        });*/
        $cookie = Cookie::forget('_token');
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'successful-logout'
        ])->withCookie($cookie);
    }
    public function hello(){
        return 'yeppp';
    }
    //
}
```

**Middleware AddAuthHeader.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AddAuthHeader
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->bearerToken()) {
            if ($request->hasCookie('_token')) {
                $token = $request->cookie('_token');
                $request->headers->add(['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token]);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
           // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
        'auth.api' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\AddAuthHeader::class,
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            'auth:api',
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
}
```

These are my approach, login working fine but when i hit axios get request for logout as below :

```
axios.get('http://localhost/uiTest/public/api/logout').then((response)=>{
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error)
            })
```

**I get below error in console:**

```
GET http://localhost/uiTest/public/api/logout 401 (Unauthorized)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js?b50d:184
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js?b50d:13
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js?5270:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js?0a06:61
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js?0a06:76
wrap @ bind.js?1d2b:9
log @ index.js?4360:51
wrappedActionHandler @ vuex.esm.js?2f62:847
dispatch @ vuex.esm.js?2f62:512
boundDispatch @ vuex.esm.js?2f62:402
log @ Navbar.vue?601a:43
click @ Navbar.vue?b169:90
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6917
index.js?4360:55 Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:69)
```

so please help me in solving this issue ??

Comment: Is your frontend going to be on the same domain add the API backend? In that case it's best to use the `CreateFreshApiToken` option, see docs. If not on same domain, than I need to know your laravel/passport version to check if you may use PKCE, again see docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport

Comment: no its not in same domain. both are in different domain. here version of passport `"laravel/passport": "^10.0"`

Comment: @Maarten sir , give me idea for it what is better to do ? got stuck on it since long days

Comment: You have several options. I advice you to stick to the login logic laravel and passport provide as much as possible, since that's most secure. You could do for a Password Client. Or you could go for PCKE. Both options are explained in the passport documenting. You need to find a way to store tokens anyway. Since you are on a different domain than your backend, you are probably also able to define a second backend? You could use that to store tokens, while your frontend talks to the API backend as much as possible.

Comment: actually i have got problem in storing token, how and where should i store it? both localstorage and cookie are not much secure so!!